# Front page meta tags and multisite configuration

Tags: multi-sites

I have a multisite install with 4 different URLs. How do I setup the meta tags (keywords and description) for each URL?

It seems like the keywords and description are the same for all of the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your sites are structured. Are all three basically the same site only available via different URLs?
First off, be aware that this can penalize you for having the same content available via multiple URLs, search engines don't like that. You should use Nodewords' ability to hardcode a specific base URL to pick one of the domains to say that one is the primary domain; the others are secondary that will help avoid penalties.

That, of course, is if you're using Drupal 6; for Drupal 7 there are other options.

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of the [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) module.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some modules to consider for answering this question (including a quote from their project pages):

- [Domain Meta Tags](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_meta).

  > Provides meta tags for individual domains by integrating [Nodewords](http://drupal.org/project/nodewords) and [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) modules. At the moment only provides keywords and description settings.
- [Nodewords Page Title (Views, Panels, Non-nodes)](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodewords_pagetitle).

  > Leverage the power of nodewords custom pages to set the page title using wildcard paths and global tokens. Great for tough-to-reach page titles in Views, Panels, and other non-node paths!
- [Nodewords by Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodewords_bypath).

  > Extends the Nodewords module to allow per path rules for populating meta tag values. If the [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module is installed, certain tokens can be used to populate the values with dynamic data.